# The CMS menu does not work in the backend panel

Tags: magento-1.9

My site was affected by guruincsite[.]com, then follow the steps to fix the problem. The CMS menu does not perform as expected, also so with backups section.

Then leave a screenshot of how it looks and does not work when you click each menu.

[image: Menu does not work]